# How to copy array_src TO> destination_array, starting at certain index at destination? ( using strcpy() )

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

A `struct node` containing `{... char opcode_CHAR[6]; }`

a pointer declared `struct node *pointer2` pointing to a node of that struct kind;

got a `char temp_array[6]`.

```
j = 6 - sizeof(temp_array);
```

So depending on the `sizeof(temp_array)`,
I will copy to a certain index `j` of `opcode_CHAR`.
If `sizeof(temp_array) == 4` ill copy to `opcode_CHAR` starting with `j = 2;`
If `sizeof(temp_array) == 2` ill copy to `opcode_CHAR` starting with `j = 4;` etc...)

I am getting a compilation warning:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

because of this: `strcpy(pointer2->opcode_CHAR[j], temp_array);`

I tried `pointer2->opcode_CHAR = pointer2->opcode_CHAR[j];` before the `strcpy(pointer2->opcode_CHAR, temp_array);` so that it points to the index `j` that I want, instead of the start of the array. But it did not work.

should I just add `j` like this? `strcpy(pointer2->opcode_CHAR+j, temp_array);`

Comment: Just skimming through this I would think that `strcpy(&(pointer2->opcode_CHAR[j]), temp_array);` should do the trick. Which should be the same as `strcpy(pointer2->opcode_CHAR+j, temp_array);`

Comment: @KamiKaze yep worked, clever. one forget sometimes that `->` is `*.` please answer it.

Comment: `var->` is `(*var).` to be precise. Then again it should be the same as `*var.` but I don't take chances with operator priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcpy` expects two pointers.

`opcode_CHAR[j]` is equivalent to `*(opcode_CHAR+j)` which is the value not the pointer.

This is why `pointer2->opcode_CHAR = pointer2->opcode_CHAR[j];` did not work you assigned a value to pointer to the array. Luckily the compiler should tell you that the array is read only, because this would have made a big mess if you would have tried to access the array afterwards.

To get the pointer to the value you want you can do `opcode_CHAR+j` as you suggested or `&opcode_CHAR[j]` which I prefer because it is more obvious.

You obviously have to get the atribute out of the struct so you have to get to the array before dereferencing:

`&(pointer2->opcode_CHAR[j])`

So the complete call would be.

`strcpy(pointer2->opcode_CHAR+j, temp_array);`

or

`strcpy(&(pointer2->opcode_CHAR[j]), temp_array);`

Please make sure that your char array is zero-terminated on `opcode_CHAR[5]`